# Outline of Trello used for Web Project / Design Management

Tags: trello

Does anyone have a good layout for using trello in Web Project / Design management?

I've got a team spread over the world and would like to switch from Basecamp (I think) to something like Trello (easier, cheaper, obviously).

Watching the video gave me some ideas, but I'm still scratching my head about the best way to begin. In order for my team to embrace this, it'll have to be almost perfect from the beginning, so I don't want to mess up :)

Comment: Do remember that Trello doesn't have chat.

Comment: Nathan,
I'm interested in this scheme too...
Maybe we both can come up with something. If you have any idea, please post it here! Thanks and good luck!

Comment: @Denis if you are interested in this you can vote up by clicking the up arrow (when you have enough reputation). Please do not use the answer link to reply to someone. With a bit more [reputation](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you can leave comments.

Comment: @phwd Trello is "missing" chat -- but that's not such thing to me, unless I'm missing something? I do wish there were a way to thread conversations, though I know that might impact the _simplicity_ of Trello (which is a "feature").

Comment: Done. But come in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/webapps I don't know if I missed any other accounts. Let me know there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My team use this scheme:

— Todo
— Doing
— Testing
— Done
— Published

For an every iteration we start a new board.

How does it works?

Let us assume we have three persons: Alice is a product manager, Bob is a developer, Charlie is a senior developer.

1. Alice adds a task in Todo list and assigns card with Bob who will do this.
2. If Bob is 100% sure he understands the task he moves the card to Doing list.
3. When task is completed Bob move it to Testing.
4. Alice moves card from Testing to Done if the task is compete else moves it to Doing (with a reason in a comment).
5. Charlie moves tasks from Done to Published when iteration is complete.

We use labels: Design, Code, Content, Admin, Bug.
Cards look like stories: "User may recover his/her password via email."
For an every client we create an organisation. Yes, clients see what we do.

That's it.

A little update on our workflow. :)

[image: Design Workflow]

Comment: That's pretty great. I've tried to keep everything in one organization, but I'm finding that one or two cards sometimes isn't really enough for some projects. For larger projects, I may consider going to a separate organization. Do you have concerns about your clients reading the comment threads? Some of our conversations are either pretty mundane or reveal our uncertainty about customer expectations, feasibility, etc...

Comment: Nathan, thank you for you comment.

Comment: We use proper language in Trello and I don't have any concerns about clients reading our comments. Even if these comment are mundane. Our clients are humans too. :) When I want to say something private I use Skype or phone. This is very rare. We have nothing to hide from our customers. This way of communication is good for healthy relationships and customer expectations. This help me to involve a client into the development process.

Answer (score 5):

Think about the path your web projects take. Usually it starts as an idea, goes to a plan, maybe goes into development or further planning, moves into testing, QA, rc, etc. Then finally it's goes from development to live. Of course, this is just an example.

Trello also publishes the Trello board for its own development flow here: https://trello.com/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c  You can use it as an example to see one specific case of web development flow.